# Would the Serpent (Satan) have dwelled eternally on earth if the fruit was not bitten?

Tags: satan, hell, resource-request, good-and-evil, eden

After Lucifer and the fallen angels were hurled away from Heaven and landed on Earth instead of hell, because Earth was once paradise before the fall of man and Satan and his demons were sent there, if Satan weren't to persuade Eve to eat of the *fruit of good and evil*, would Satan and his demons live in earth forever and would have not been damned.

Have any biblical scholars or theologians written the question following: **Would the Serpent (Satan) have dwelled eternally on earth if the fruit was not bitten?**

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We look for well-researched questions and answers that are not opinion-based.  Please take our Tour to improve your question and avoid answers that simply give opinions: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I made this a resource request in order to avoid the question being an opinion based one. Hope this meets your approval, **thegamerguy**!

Comment: The order of events in your narrative is off

Comment: @thegamerguy Our world (earth + universe) is not eternal.  The eternal is the restored/recreated [New Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Earth_(Christianity)) after the [day of judgment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Judgment) where Satan and his minions are thrown to hell.

Answer (score 0):

Muslim here, this question revolves around a scenario pointing to an answer based on guessing, and it's not in our authority to speculate what God wrote in destiny.

Something to think about:

> John 8:58 Jesus said unto them, Verily, verily, I say unto you, Before Abraham was, I am.

No matter how you interpret the verse, Jesus was already **destined** to come for Israel before God creates Abraham, Jesus grandfather.

This means God planned the entire creation before creating Adam himself, and since the question is about Satan, you can also say the descent of Adam and Eve to the earth was also planned by God, but an atheist can snipe for a hole in this plot.

The good/evil dilemma concerns theologians and philosophers about Adam's story, an atheist presumes God doesn't like Adam by leaving Satan to take him out of Eden, so Christianity resolves this by the concept of Original Sin.

It's actually not explained in Genesis whether God promised Adam to dwell in Eden eternally or [instead] planned for Adam's descent to earth [without telling him], was God really **teaching** Adam about life hardships with that tree He left in Eden?

The chronological order of Genesis is:

1. God created the universe [i.e. Heavens].
2. God created earth, then life on it.
3. God created man.

Adam's descent didn't happen due to coincidence or plan B, **God destined it,** and you can see that in Genesis 3:16-19, everything was put in a predetermined order for a mission Adam had to do on the earth.

With God's destiny, Adam and his descendants had free will to walk upon God's plan:

**Deuteronomy 30**

> 16 In that I command thee this day to love the LORD thy God, to walk in his ways, and to keep his commandments and his statutes and his judgments, that thou mayest live and multiply: and the LORD thy God shall bless thee in the land whither thou goest to possess it.
>
> 17 But if thine heart turn away, so that thou wilt not hear, but shalt be drawn away, and worship other gods, and serve them;
>
> 18 I denounce unto you this day, that ye shall surely perish.

So the question that Satan will have an alternative destiny will not work [no matter the proposed answer] if we can't guess what scenario did God plan to occur.

Personal advice, always avoid speculative questions, they do more harm than good.

Comment: Since the Lamb (Christ) was slain from before the foundation of the world (in God's economy) even though he was not actually slain until "just the right time" we can reasonably deduce that God's foreknowledge (He knows the end from the beginning) that the serpent would tempt Eve and that Adam would fall rules out an alternative destiny for Satan.  In other words, there is no possibility that the serpent would not have tempted Eve resulting in Adam's fall and our inheritance of sin and death.

Comment: @MikeBorden That's the TLDR, even that Satan also has free will, God created earth before creating Adam, so everything was prepared from the start that Adam can do his quest. Whether Adam obeyed Satan and ate from the tree or not, God would have surely gave Adam the order [later] to descend from Eden with Eve, but to give Adam a lesson that life is not for free. It's fact that God didn't promise Adam a permanent stay there, so the question of the OP [technically] has no answer.

Comment: My point is that God knew Adam would disobey and had already planned, before creation, to send his Son as an atoning sacrifice to reconcile the world to Himself.  I agree the question has no answer because God already knew the serpent would tempt Eve and succeed.

Comment: You forget the "Beginning" in Genesis chronological order. God created the "Beginning", the question is who is the "Beginning". Answer : "The Virgin is the Beginning".-Luisa Picarreta, why? Because the Virgin or the chosen Woman is "God's dream in eternity". And, God created the Heavens  Earth out of love, because "Love begins with a Dream". And God was moved to create to fulfill His dream, the God of Love desires to be love by a daughter, a Mother and a Spouse. "Mary is God's dream in eternity", the reason why God creates the Heavens and the Earth and and all creatures.

Comment: @jongricafort I believe the Jews will disagree with that interpretation of "Beginning" since you are mixing John 1 with Genesis. Yet where was Jesus in the beginning?

Comment: @AhmedAli God created the "beginning", all the living and material creation "out of love", the creation of life was based on love, but "Love begins with a dream" said Bl.Ab.Fulton Sheen. If love begins with a dream, the next question to ponder is, did God dream of something to possess in eternity? Something that God do not have? Yes!, God dream to possess a "Woman", the God of Love desires to be love by a chosen Woman, and so, to experience the love of a Woman, the Almighty God willed to become a helpless child in the loving arms of a Woman. the Madonna is God's vision of Himself in eternity.